# how to show different object field in table

Tags: apex

I have a custom object name order under the opportunity object. I want to create a table which field are status which is field of opportunity and another attribute name price which is field of order custom object. how to create such table in visualforce.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a simple vf page page with pageblocktable to do this.
Query the opportunity object with status and price from order.

```
select status,(select price from order) from opportunity
```

Access the list from vf page in pageblocktable.

```
<apex:pageblocktable value={!listyouwant} var="lyw">
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Opp Status</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputtext value="{!lyw.status}" />
</apex:column>
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Price</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputtext value="{!lyw.price}" />
</apex:column>
```

This should give you the required table.

Answer (score 0):

If sounds like `Opportunity` is the parent object so the query would be on the child:

```
select Opportunity__r.Status__c, Price__c from Order__c where ...
```

and the Visualforce would be:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value={!list} var="item">
    <apex:column value="{!item.Opportunity__r.Status__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!item.Price__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

(You will need to double check the relationship name `Opportunity__r`. See [Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects) for more information.)